# when can i skip './' in HTML relative path?

Tags: relative-path

When i found about relative path, Many documents said i can skip `./` for current folder path.

But when i publish github pages, that path (skip `./` => `images/name.jpg`) doesn't work. (The index.html and images folder are in same location.)

So I fixed it to `./images/name.jpg`, and it works!

I have question about that.
`images/name.jpg` <- this one, why doesn't it work?
Is there any condition to skip `./`??

+++++
Actually I use many images and there codes are `images/name.jpg`. Most of them works well but only a few images doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/images/name.jpg` because `index.html` and `images folder` are in the same directory.

( use `/` for a folder, `images/name.jpg` didn't has `/` in front of the `images` folder. )

Edit:

You can refer to this document.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: Thanks for help !! Can I ask one more thing? Actually I use many images and there code was `images/name.jpg`, most of them works well but only a few images doesn't work. I forgot to write on my question post sorry  My question is, if error was because of `/` for folder, Why did the rest of things (I mean `images/name.jpg`) are work?

Comment: I saw your Edit and now my curiosity has been solved !! Thanks a lot !!!!!